# jQuery rotate image (using rotate plugin) rotate +/-90 degrees each click

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, rotation

I am using this jQuery plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation

I have the plugin working and everything, however what I want to be able to do is to click a button to rotate the image, and each time you click the button it rotates +/- 90 degrees continuously, not just to a certain degree. I'm not quite sure how I could accomplish this with this plugin.

Ideally the code below would do what I want, though it doesn't.

```
$("body").on("click", ".theater-wrapper img", function(){

    $(".theater-wrapper .current").rotate(+90);

});
```

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't just be `$(".theater-wrapper .current").rotate(90);`

Comment: Well, either way it still does what the plugin is suppose to do, the +90 was just something I put to see if that would do what I want it to do, but it doesn't, however it still works - it rotates it to 90 degrees, but that's it. What I want it to do is the first click to rotate it to 90 degrees, then the second click it would go to 180 degrees (+90 degrees), then to 270, 360, 450 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("body").on("click", ".theater-wrapper img", function(){

    $(".theater-wrapper .current").rotate(getNextAngle());

});

nextAngle = 0;
function getNextAngle() {
    nextAngle += 90;    
    if(nextAngle >= 360) {
        nextAngle = 0;
    }
    return nextAngle;
}
```

Probably not a big deal, but to avoid getting a huge number you could reset the value to 0 when needed.

Comment: That's actually perfect, thanks! Now I know I didn't include this in my question, but would you happen to know if there is any way to change the image's DOM position, so when I use jquery's height() on the rotated image it would know that it's now rotated and the position is different. (i have to use jquery to calculate the max image height/width for my theater viewer.

Comment: Use the plugins callback function that fires upon completeion to recalculate and set it's new position.

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/jKYkT/

Click on **+** and **-** button for the angle rotation

Hope this fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
newangle = 0;

$('input').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == "minus")
        operation = "-";
    else
        operation = "+";

    alert(operation)
    var angle = next(operation);
    $("#image").rotate(angle);
});

function next(oper) {
   if (oper == "+")
      newangle += 90;
    else
      newangle -= 90;

   if (newangle >= 360) newangle = 0;

    return newangle;

}


​
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at the plugin but what I'm assuming it does is use cross-browser supported CSS3 transform rotates. It's always going to need a specific angle, so you're going to have to track your current angle with a variable of some sort. A good solution might be an HTML5 data tag that you increment on each click, especially if you want to have multiple images with rotations in your DOM. So say your HTML is this:

```
<div class='image_wrap'>
    <img class='image_to_rotate' />
    <div class='rotate_btn' data-rotate='0'></div>
</div>
```

So when the user clicks the rotate button, it will grab this variable and increment it by 90, and then store the new value in the same place so it's ready to increment it on the next click. Your jQuery might look like this:

```
$('.rotate_btn').click(function(){
    //Grab the current set angle
    var angle = parseInt($(this).data('rotate')) + 90;

    //Rotate the image
    $(this).siblings('.image_to_rotate').rotate(angle);

    //Store new angle for next increment
    $(this).data('rotate', angle);
})
```

This isn't tested but you should have enough to go on here. Check out the jQuery documentation on .data if you need further guidance.

Comment: Ahh he beat me to it, consider a class based approach with data attributes if you need multiple instances and such as your javascript might get messy. And including some logic to reset to zero after 270 is a good idea. You'll need more logic if you want to have left and right rotation btns.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rotation = 0;
$("body").on("click", ".theater-wrapper img", function(){
    rotation +=90;
    $(".theater-wrapper .current").rotate({ animateTo:rotation });
});
```

or

```
var rotation = 0;
$("body").on("click", ".theater-wrapper img", function(){
    rotation +=90;
    var rotation_angle_mod = rotation%360;
    $(".theater-wrapper .current").rotate(rotation_angle_mod);
});
```